# Yeoman Generator fails with assertion error related to this.copy

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

This is an older Yeoman generator that was setup using ***this.copy***

```
this.copy('_editorconfig', '.editorconfig');
```

ERROR: AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Trying to copy from a source that does not exist: _editorconfig

Answer (score 0):

The fix was due to changes in the way copy was handled.

```
    this.fs.copy(
        this.templatePath('_editorconfig'),
        this.destinationPath('.editorconfig')
    );
```

As a note this also was a fix for adding a gitignore

```
    this.fs.copy(
        this.templatePath('_gitignore'),
        this.destinationPath('.gitignore')
    );
```